# How can I gear my follower post 2.0?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm a little confused as to how I'm supposed to gear up my follower since the installation of smart loot in Loot 2.0. My follower still has most pre loot 2.0 items because I have yet to find comparables that are rolling with the right affixes.

To be clear, I play a DH and so I used the Templar as my tank. I very rarely find items that roll with Strength because smart loot sees my DH and rolls Dex for me instead. With the use of the Enchantress I thought it would get better because I could replace Dex with Strength...but that's not true. It seems as though the Enchantress will only roll Dex for me too.

With the auction house down for good, no outlet for trading, and the installation of smart loot, it seems that gearing a follower has become almost impossible unless I want to jump on another character that uses strength and get items that way. I want to find items that I can use while I'm playing. How do I gear my follower post Loot 2.0? Do I have any options other than character jumping?

Comment: You'll just have to pony up the gold for rerolling with another character.  At least they fixed the glitch where the legendary relic rolled the wrong stat due to 'smart loot'.  I had to roll my Templar relic on my barb.

Comment: You can still get items that do not roll your stats. I sometimes find that I've picked up agility or intellect gear on my crusader. That being said, it is a lot more efficient to roll a strength class to gear a templar.

Comment: You could always jump on any character depending on which primary you want to roll, and _craft_ level 70 items at the black smith. More costly but it can be done at any time since crafting has no character level requirement.

Comment: Great question.  I actually have gotten 3 level 70s since I started playing again and when I do solo farming I like to have a follower (even if nothing more than a damage sponge) and I realized my enchantress was doing 2 dmg per attack.

Comment: Not all drops are smart loot. I still find str/dex gear on my wizard for example, it just takes longer. But given the tiny damage that followers do, I am also not agonizing over min/maxing their gear.

Comment: Things like this make me question why Blizzard clings to having three different primary stats (+vitality), instead of just combining them into, say "Power". No one uses "cross-class" stats. At All. Ever.

Answer (score 8):

I use some "tricks" to gear my enchantress/templar with my DH however I admit none of them is really convenient. Since Loot 2.0 will screw the roll most of the time, if you don't want to play another character just for looting gear for your follower you can:

- Use another character to simply reroll the dex into intelligence/strength.
- Use another character to craft an item with the blacksmith.
- Use another character to spend BloodShard at Kadala (and get Strength items with a Barbarian/Templar and Intelligence items with a Wizard/Witch Doctor). However this require to level up the betting character up to 70 since Kadala hands item of the level of the character you're currently playing with.
- Ask a friend who plays Wizard/Witch Doctor/Barbarian/Crusader to keep some rings/amulet with good roll of strength/intel and reroll one of the primary attribute into something you'd like (vitality/crit hit damage etc.)

That's the only ways I've found so far in order to gear my follower correctly. Then if you are "lucky" you can still loot legendaries that are not for DH (like 1H swords/axes or staffs) that almost never roll dex but instead roll the main attribute of the class the item was designed for (I regularly loot swords with strength or staffs with intelligence).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "roll?"

Comment: @Mkalafut rol is the term used to designate the random properties an item get in Diablo 3. A good roll = an item with good properties. A NPC in the game allow you to reroll (= rerandom) one of the porperty on each of your item.

Comment: thanks.  I figured that was the case but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Another option is to farm Bloodshards in Rifts with the Demon Hunter, then spend them at Kadala with a character that has the targeted primary stat (i.e. Barbarian/Crusader for Templar gear, and Wizard/Witch Doctor for Enchantress gear).

Comment: @drovani good point

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use items with no primary stats( int, str, dex ) if/when you find them. 
For instance, if an amulet rolls:

- min-max damage
- crit chance
- crit damage
- atk speed

it is not that bad to throw away. Your follower would be happy to use it.  Maybe the damage is not the best, but nor that horrible! ;)

Comment: I don't recommend this though, followers naturally gain a huge multiplier boost from any stats on gear they equip, you are giving up a lot to use items with no stats.

Comment: I didn't mean that, maybe I explained myself a bit bad. I would tell you can give up, for instance, strenght if you are using templar, and use something with damage, crit and crit damage. The stat I wrote are supposed to be rolled together! ^^'

Answer (score 0):

An option that has not thus far been mentioned in the other answers, is to reroll the primary stat on some gear using the Enchantress. For the example given (DH with Templar companion), that would mean rerolling Dexterity to Strength.